# How do I change DataBinding index position programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, generic-list

How do I change DataBinding index position programmatically?

For Example: I have a `list<>` collection named **`MYLIST<T>`** and two controls placed on form **TEXTBOX1** and **LISTBOX1** both controls are bind with `MYLIST<T>`.

at the time of execusion, LISTBOX control get filled from MYLIST and when I am clicking on LISTBOX1-Item, TEXTBOX1.Text changing as per selected index of MYLIST as both are controls are bind with MY LIST.

I want to set list index position 2 programmatically. like when I click on a button so TEXTBOX1.Text should change as per list index[2], the same behaviour when clicking second item of LISTBOX1.

I have tried .Select but no luck,

here is sample code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public sealed class Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    private List<Person> myList = new List<Person>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myList.Add(new Person(){name = "MyName1"});
        myList.Add(new Person(){name = "MyName2"});
        myList.Add(new Person(){name = "MyName3"});

        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", myList, "name"));

        listBox1.DataSource = myList;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
        listBox1.ValueMember= "name";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myList.Select(person => person.name.StartsWith("MyName2"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
BindingContext[myList].Position = myList.FindIndex(person => person.name.StartsWith("MyName2"));
```

You may find useful reading the following MSDN links [BindingContext Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) and
 [Control.BindingContext Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bindingcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @HaseebAhmed When you find your answer, you can kindly click on check mark near the answer to accept it. You can only check one answer  as accepted while you can vote up as many answers as you find helpful by click on up arrow near the answer. This way it will be more helpful for other users in future. Also you can vote up good questions.